# Regular session High Low Midline (50%) plus 25 and 75 percent lines

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I am using a script that shows the regular trading day high, low and midline (50%). I am trying to include a 25% and 75% line in there as well but I am getting a Compilation error. Line 16: Cannot call 'operator +' with argument 'expr1'='m'. An argument of 'plot' type was used but a 'series float' is expected
line 17: Cannot call 'operator +' with argument 'expr1'='m'. An argument of 'plot' type was used but a 'series float' is expected.

I have no clue how to go about this. Can anyone help please?

```
//@version=5

indicator("test 25 75 Regular Session High Low Mid", overlay=true)


D_High = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on) 
D_Low = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on) 

var float m = na

plot(timeframe.isintraday ? D_High : na, title="Reg Sess High", style=plot.style_circles, color=#ff0000,linewidth=1)
m = plot((D_High + D_Low) / 2, title="Reg Sess Mid", style=plot.style_circles, color=#ffeb3b, linewidth=1)
plot(timeframe.isintraday ? D_Low : na, title="Reg Sess Low", style=plot.style_circles, color=#ff0000,linewidth=1) 
s = plot((D_High + m) / 2, title="Reg Sess 75%", style=plot.style_circles, color=#ffeb3b, linewidth=1)
q = plot((D_Low + m) / 2, title="Reg Sess 25%", style=plot.style_circles, color=#ffeb3b, linewidth=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//@version=5
indicator("test 25 75 Regular Session High Low Mid", overlay=true)

[D_High, D_Low, D_50, D_75, D_25] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', [high, low, hl2, (high+hl2)/2, (low+hl2)/2], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on) 

plot(timeframe.isintraday ? D_High : na, title="Reg Sess High", style=plot.style_circles, color=#ff0000, linewidth=1)
plot(timeframe.isintraday ? D_50   : na, title="Reg Sess Mid",  style=plot.style_circles, color=#ffeb3b, linewidth=1)
plot(timeframe.isintraday ? D_Low  : na, title="Reg Sess Low",  style=plot.style_circles, color=#ff0000, linewidth=1) 
plot(timeframe.isintraday ? D_75   : na, title="Reg Sess 75%",  style=plot.style_circles, color=#ffeb3b, linewidth=1) 
plot(timeframe.isintraday ? D_25   : na, title="Reg Sess 25%",  style=plot.style_circles, color=#ffeb3b, linewidth=1)
```

Comment: So the only issue with the script above is that it only works in real-time. If I try to back test it, it still only shows the results of the end of day plots. I have another script that I use for back-testing but I cannot seem to figure out how to add the 25 and 72 % plot lines. Also it's an old version script, ver 2.

Comment: //@version=2
study("Regular Session High Low Mid", overlay=true)
t = time("390", session.regular) // 390=60*6.5 is the number of minutes in a whole day. You may use "0930-1600" as second session parameter
//plot(t, style=linebr) // debug
is_first = na(t[1]) and not na(t) or t[1] < t
plotshape(is_first, color=red, style=shape.arrowdown)

Comment: day_high = na
day_low = na

if is_first and barstate.isnew
    day_high := high
    day_low := low
else
    day_high := day_high[1]
    day_low := day_low[1]

if high > day_high
    day_high := high
    
if low < day_low
    day_low := low

Comment: plot(day_high, color=lime)
plot(day_low, color=red)
m = plot((day_low + day_high) / 2, color=yellow)

Comment: This script allows me to use the replay mode and it follows the time in replay mode, it does not show the end of the day results like the other script does.